# Weird gaps showing up under header when loaded in IE 9

Tags: html, google-chrome

I've been scratching my head looking for a solution to this "common gap problem".

Here's what the page's like in Chrome & how the page is like in IE9 https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3788693/Work/example.jpg

Here's my HTML file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3788693/Work/01index.html

I've read lots about using and applying

```
Setting position:relative on the header block.
Setting position:absolute; top:0; right:0
#header img { display: block }
```

But it just doesn't seem to show any change in IE. Perhaps i'm applying the wrong things in the wrong place? Anyhow, why is it different in IE in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conditional comment for IE you're using

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
/* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
.twoColElsLtHdr #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.twoColElsLtHdr #mainContent { zoom: 1; padding-top: 15px; }
/* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it needs to avoid several bugs */
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Removing `padding-top: 30px` from `.twoColElsLtHdr #sidebar1` and `padding-top: 15px` from `.twoColElsLtHdr #sidebar1` will take care of the gap you're seeing.

Comment: Oh... Thank you good sir T_T You have shown me the way! I always thought that the if conditional statement is "commented". I never guessed that IE would use that as a conditional statement. That's what i get for skipping classes X_X again, THANK YOU!

Comment: would it be alright if i added another question regarding anomalies shown by IE? I have one more prob.

Comment: @faerismAsksAlot - It'd probably be better to ask another question than to add to this one.